# Populate the list view using specific data from the Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help with displaying data from the firebase console. So the scene is that I have put some data in the console using a seperate class called "TicketSubmitted". I need to display some of the children of the data in a list view in the "MainActivity". The model class for the MainActivity is called "Ticket" and the adapter for the list view is called "TicketAdapter"

the code for the MainActivity is:

```
package com.android.example.ithelpdesk;
//imports

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawer;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
public TicketAdapter adapter;
private final static  int RC_SIGN_IN = 2;
public String mUsername;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mUsername = user.getUid();

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                onSignedInInitialized(user.getDisplayName());
            } else {
                onSignedOutCleanup();
                startActivityForResult(
                        getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTicket);
   final ArrayList<String> arrayOfTicket = new ArrayList<>()
    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                                                     Ticket ticket = (Ticket)dataSnapshot.getValue(Ticket.class);
                                                     adapter.add(ticket);
                                                 }

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                                                 }

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                                 }

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                                                 }

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                 }
                                             }

    );mDatabaseReference.

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        }
    });

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ComplaintDetail.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.complaintbutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(View view) {
                                      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TicketCategory.class);
                                      startActivity(intent);
                                  }
                              }
    );

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_settings:
        {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
            return true;
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void detachDatabaseReadListener()
{
    if(mChildEventListener != null)
    {
        mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        mChildEventListener = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

private void onSignedInInitialized(String username)
{
    mUsername = username;
   // attachDatabaseReadListener();
}

private void onSignedOutCleanup()
{
    mUsername = null;

}
```

The model class Ticket:

```
public class Ticket {
public String TicketCategory;
 // public String Name;
public String Subcategory;
public String priority;
private String status;
private String comments;
private String cannedReply;


public Ticket (String TicketCategory, String Subcategory, String priority, String status, String comments, String cannedReply)
{
    this.TicketCategory = TicketCategory;
 //   this.Name = Name;
    this.Subcategory = Subcategory;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.status = status;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.cannedReply = cannedReply;
}


public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTicketCategory() {
    return TicketCategory;
}

//public String getName(){return Name;}

public String getSubcategory() {
    return Subcategory;
}

public String getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public String getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public String getCannedReply() {
    return cannedReply;
}

public void setCannedReply(String cannedReply) {
    this.cannedReply = cannedReply;
}

public String getStatus() {
   return status;

}

public static ArrayList<Ticket> getTicket()
{
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
    return tickets;
}}
```

The code for the adapter TicketAdapter is:

```
public class TicketAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ticket> {

TicketAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Ticket> tickets) {
    super(context, 0, tickets);
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    Ticket ticket = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tickets, parent, false);
    }

    TextView tvCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TicketCategory);
    TextView tvSubcategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Subcategory);
    TextView tvPriority = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priority);


    assert ticket != null;
    tvCategory.setText(ticket.TicketCategory);
    tvSubcategory.setText(ticket.Subcategory);
    tvPriority.setText(ticket.priority);


    return convertView;

}}
```

I just want to display the TicketCategory, Subcategory and priority in a set manner in the list view but i am unable to do so. Also when I introduce a new childEventListener, i get this error and the app crashes:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsCbD.png)

I am new at android programming so any input will be appreciated...

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your log say that you need to rename your `Ticket` fields like (can't start with an uppercase) :

```
public String ticketCategory;
public String subcategory;
```

Then you must instanciate your `adapter` with your `arrayOfTicket` and then set the `adapter` to your `ListView` (+ don't forget to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you add/remove object in your list) :

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTicket);
final ArrayList<Ticket> arrayOfTicket = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new TicketAdapter(this, arrayOfTicket); // Instanciate your adapter
listView.setAdapter(adapter); // Set the adapter to your ListView
mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        Ticket ticket = (Ticket)dataSnapshot.getValue(Ticket.class);
        adapter.add(ticket);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify for changes to reload the list
    }

    ...
```

Comment: adapter wont accept ArrayList in string. Also I'm still getting the error with the crashing of the app. i have linked the screenshot in the question. :(

Comment: I tried this but im getting: java.lang.nullpointerexception: attempt to invoke virtual method 'int.java.lang.hashCode' on a null object reference.

Comment: thanks a lot! i was able to do it. i didnt add a default constructor in the Ticket activity. thank you for you help!!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: subcategory
```

Please change the following lines of code:

```
public String TicketCategory;
// public String Name;
public String Subcategory;
public String priority;
```

to

```
private String TicketCategory;
// private String Name;
private  String Subcategory;
private  String priority;
```

And don't forget to add the no-argument constructor in your `Ticket` class.

```
public Ticket() {} //Needed for Firebase
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is in the way that you refer to the data, you don't seem to refer to the actual node that must list the data.

lets say your node that you save the data in is called `Tickets`

so instead of this:

```
 mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {....
```

do this:

```
 DatabaseReference tickets_ref = mDatabaseReference.child("Tickets");
 tickets_ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {....
```

instead of this:

```
final ArrayList<String> arrayOfTicket = new ArrayList<>();
```

do this:

```
final ArrayList<Ticket> arrayOfTicket = new ArrayList<>();
```

now after this:

```
final ArrayList<Ticket> arrayOfTicket = new ArrayList<>();
```

initialize the adapter like this:

```
 adapter = new TicketAdapter(context,arrayOfTicket);
```

and instead of this:

```
adapter.add(ticket);
```

do this:

```
arrayOfTicket.add(ticket);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```